# How to see command history with Ideavim

Tags: vim, ideavim

I can do so in vim with `q:`, but that doesn't work with Ideavim.

Seeing the command history is really useful for find and replace command history, and would make this plugin really nice.

Comment: IdeaVim is not Vim. There's no reason whatsoever to expect any Vim thing to work in IdeaVim.

Comment: This is a [requested feature](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-833) but has not yet been implemented. Feel free to submit a pull request [on github](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim).

Comment: how about `:history`?

Comment: Thank your for providing substitution! It will make my work more effective!